# Postlet upload test will work but not the applet

Tags: java, php, applet

I'm using a java HTTP uploading applet called "Postlet". I set up the PHP script to store the file and store the file name in the database. When I use a simple HTML test form to upload one picture, it works fine but it doesn't work when I use the actual applet even if I only select one file.

The java applet acts as if everything was successful reporting that the image upload was a success but the file is nowhere to be found. I even used a new applet with a simplified PHP file and the applet again says everything was successful.  But it didn't input anything into the database nor did it upload the file.

My script is here minus some MySQL stuff and file directories for safety measures :P

```
<?php
session_start();


$albumID = $_SESSION['albumID'];
$author = 1;
/*
The following file enables the uploading of each image from the java applet.

PLEASE NOTE, THIS FILES IN ITS PRESENT FORM IS A MASSIVE SECURITY RISK, AND
SHOULD NOT BE USED WITHOUT DOING EITHER OF THE FOLLOWING:

- PROTECTING THE ACCESS OF THE FILE BY THE USE OF SESSION VARIABLES (DO NOT
  PROTECT IT BY USING HTTP PASSWORDS)
- ENSURING THAT UPLOADED FILES ARE NOT ACCESSIBLE TO THE WEB (UPLOAD FILES
  TO A DIRECTORY ABOVE THE DOCUMENT ROOT)
*/

/*
AS OF POSTLET 0.11, POSTLET READS THE MESSAGES SENT BACK TO IT, AND NOW
IS AWARE OF WHETHER OR NOT AN UPLOAD HAS BEEN SUCCESSFUL. MORE INFORMATION
ABOUT THE FORMAT OF REPLY MESSAGES CAN BE FOUND ON THE POSTLET WEBSITE 
http://www.postlet.com/install/
*/

// Configuration ---------------------------------------------------------------
// Change the below path to the folder where you would like files uploading.
// e.g. "/home/yourname/myuploads/"
// or "c:\php\uploads\"
// Note, this MUST have the trailing slash.
$sql = "SELECT folder FROM albums WHERE id='".$albumID."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$album = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$albumFolder = $album['folder'];
// Whether or not to allow the upload of specific files
$allow_or_deny = true;
// If the above is true, then this states whether the array of files is a list of
// extensions to ALLOW, or DENY
$allow_or_deny_method = "allow"; // "allow" or "deny"
$file_extension_list = array("jpg","png");
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($allow_or_deny){
    if (($allow_or_deny_method == "allow" && !in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']))), $file_extension_list))
        || ($allow_or_deny_method == "deny" && in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']))), $file_extension_list))){      
        // Atempt to upload a file with a specific extension when NOT allowed.
        // 403 error
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        echo "POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:NO\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:FILE TYPE NOT ALLOWED\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:ABORT THIS\r\n"; // Postlet should NOT send this file again.
        echo "END POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        exit;
    }
}
$newFileName = time() . "-" . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$newFileName))
{   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images(file, album, author) VALUES('".$newFileName."', '".$albumID."', '".$author."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
    // All replies MUST start with "POSTLET REPLY", if they don't, then Postlet will
    // not read the reply and will assume the file uploaded successfully.
    echo "POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
    // "YES" tells Postlet that this file was successfully uploaded.
    echo "POSTLET:YES\r\n";
    // End the Postlet reply
    echo "END POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
    exit;
    } else {
        echo "Could not store into database";
    }
} 
else
{
    // If the file can not be uploaded (most likely due to size), then output the
    // correct error code
    // If $_FILES is EMPTY, or $_FILES['userfile']['error']==1 then TOO LARGE
    if (count($_FILES)==0 || $_FILES['userfile']['error']==1){
        // All replies MUST start with "POSTLET REPLY", if they don't, then Postlet will
        // not read the reply and will assume the file uploaded successfully.
        echo "POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:NO\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:TOO LARGE\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:ABORT THIS\r\n"; // Postlet should NOT send this file again.
        echo "END POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        exit;
    }
    // Unable to write the file to the server ALL WILL FAIL
    else if ($_FILES['userfile']['error']==6 || $_FILES['userfile']['error']==7){
        // All replies MUST start with "POSTLET REPLY", if they don't, then Postlet will
        // not read the reply and will assume the file uploaded successfully.
        echo "POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:NO\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:SERVER ERROR\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:ABORT ALL\r\n"; // Postlet should NOT send any more files
        echo "END POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        exit;
    }
    // Unsure of the error here (leaves 2,3,4, which means try again)
    else {
        // All replies MUST start with "POSTLET REPLY", if they don't, then Postlet will
        // not read the reply and will assume the file uploaded successfully.
        echo "POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:NO\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:UNKNOWN ERROR\r\n";
        echo "POSTLET:RETRY\r\n";
        print_r($_REQUEST); // Possible usefull for debugging
        echo "END POSTLET REPLY\r\n";
        exit;
    }
}


?>
```

Any idea why it might not be working?

Comment: I've edited your comment into the (good) question.  You might delete the comment now.  If I have any inspirations I'll get back to you.  It sounds as thought you might do some debugging in the PHP as to what is actually arriving.